# Has anyone tracked down whether IronPython or IronRuby will support Attributes?

Tags: ironpython, ironruby

I have scanned 'the Google' and have not found the definitive answer on whether the Iron* languages (any or all) will end up with Attribute support..

Anyone?

Thanks - Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some discussion about the plans in the ironpython mailing list recently - [link text](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.ironpython.com/msg08218.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of last August IronRuby [did not have Attribute support](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/ironruby-core/2008-August/002633.html) yet, and I haven't seen any recent announcements about it since then, but it is definitely a planned feature.

Answer (score 0):

We're looking at attribute support again for a .NET interop-focused release in the near future. Keep an eye on ironruby-core@rubyforge.org for an updates.